# Return the names of people that have half the wealth of the richest person

Tags: sql

For an assignment i must combine 3 tables and write a query that returns the names of all people that have less than half of the wealth of the richest person. We define the wealth of a person as the total money on all of his/her accounts.

The 3 tables are:

---

**Persons**

id  |  name   |   address  |  age  |  eyeColor |  gender

---

**BankAccounts**

id    |   balance

---

**AccountOf**

id | person_id → Persons | account_id → BankAccounts

I know how to use te SUM() function and the MAX() function, but combining them is a pain in my ass.
There is also someone without an bankaccount.
Does anyone know how to do this assignment or can give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Use subquery to identify richest person.

Comment: Please add what you have tried even through it might not get you the right result. and a sqlfiddle if possible.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: @deterministicFail These assignment questions are not DBMS related

Comment: Been messing around a bit and am even further from the answer. I now have:
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(B.balance) as money, P1.name
FROM Persons P1, BankAccounts B, AccountOf A

WHERE P1.id = A.person_id
AND B.id = A.account_id
GROUP BY P1.name

Answer (score 2):

Not to give it away, since it's an assignment and that kind of ruins the whole thing, but... you'll need to find the sum(balance) for the richest person, which would be the max of all the persons' sum(balance). This will look something like:

```
SELECT
    max(personbalance)
FROM
    (
        Select 
            sum(balance)
        FROM
            persons
            join accountof
            join bankaccounts
        GROUP BY persons.id
    )subForSum
```

This will just be a subquery in your main query, but it should give you enough direction to slap the rest of it together. When in doubt with these things, just subquery and subquery and subquery. You can clean it up after you get the answer you expect.

Answer (score 0):

For future students who are looking for an answer:

- Use a left Join as some persons might not be in the BankAccount table
- Obtain null value and use coalesce to replace the values
- use this as a subquery to obtain the richest person and compare values:

```
    SELECT max(personbalance)  
    FROM  
        (  
        Select   
            sum(balance)  
        FROM  
            persons  
            join accountof  
            join bankaccounts  
        GROUP BY persons.id  
    )
```

Good Luck!