# SQL aggregated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I want to query the persons who have got less wealth than half of the wealth of the richest person. So I came up with the following query:

```
select P.name
from
    (select sum(B.balance) / 2 as Balance
    from Person P1, BankAccount B, AccountOf A
    where P.id = A.person_id and A.account_id = B.id
    group by P1.id) as X, Persons P, BankAccount B, AccountOf A
    
where  
group by P.id
having sum(B.balance) < max(X.Balance)
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, it seems to me that something goes wrong in the normal query as the subquery done separately gives the right amount.

Comment: ANSI-92 is the standard adopted to replace implicit joins *(using `,`)* with an explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That's very nearly 30 years old.  Please ***stop*** using out-dated and error prone syntax from the wrong century.  Doing so will help you get queries right the first time, and then be easier to debug too.  *(For example, you have **no** join predicates on the outer query, which is an impossible accident to occur if you use `JOIN` syntax.)*

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for responding man. I am learning through my university. But I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "query the persons who have got less wealth than half of the wealth of the richest"

```
select id,Name
from (
        select
            P.id,P.Name
            sum(B.balance) as Balance,
            max(sum(B.balance)) over() richestbalance
        from
            Person P
            join BankAccount B on P.id = A.person_id
            join AccountOf A on A.account_id = B.id
        group by P.id,P.Name
    ) t
where Balance < richestbalance / 2
```

then to use your query:

```
select P.name
from
    (select sum(B.balance) as Balance
    from Person P1, BankAccount B, AccountOf A
    where P.id = A.person_id and A.account_id = B.id
    group by P1.id) as X, Persons P, BankAccount B, AccountOf A
    
where  ...
group by P.id
having sum(B.balance) < max(X.Balance)/2
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: as I am doing this through college, I the subquery part is not allowed as it gives an error for the wrong use of the group function. Is there a way to fix this similar to what I had tried in the original question?

Comment: I don't see any syntax error in the query , which dbms are you using? even your query has a subquery with group by in it

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(B.balance) as Balance, max(sum(B.balance)) over() richestbalanc' at line 5. This is the error I am getting, but the system is probably very old as the question from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835007/return-the-names-of-people-that-have-half-the-wealth-of-the-richest-person is from 6 years ago and has the same problem. @eshirvana

Comment: aha , which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: I am sorry but it is in an online tool to submit the answers in, so I cannot be certain, but it seems pretty old. @eshirvana